# How to choose a proper filter for an sql join

Tags: sql

If I have table A and table B, each with one column:

```
A:
col1
1
2
3
1

B:
col1
1
1
4
```

and I want all rows from A and the matching rows from B, only when the column has non null value in both tables, which one should I use?

```
select * from A left join B on A.col1 = B.col1 and A.col1 is not null AND B.col1 is not null;

select * from A left join B on A.col1 = B.col1 where A.col1 is not null OR B.col1 is not null;

select * from A left join B on A.col1 = B.col1 and (A.col1 is not null OR B.col1 is not null;)
```

My guess is that the first and the third are the same and will provide the desired output.

Comment: _"when the column is not null in both tables"_ why do you check it in the query when the column is not nullable anyway?

Comment: The statements are not the same. The first uses AND, the second OR.

Comment: Sorry, i meant first and third will give same output

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip null values and you want to link both tables only on existing values you should use an [`INNER JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join), the null check is redundant:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.col1 = B.col1
```

`NULL` will never match any other value (not even `NULL` itself), unless the join condition explicitly uses the `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` predicates.

Comment: Thanks. Actually null is just an example...I need to check for nulls, empty strings and junk values like 'N/A'

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you said you are checking for more than nulls in this case I would probaly take thederived table or CTE approach. Dervied table shown below as you did not specify which database backend, so I don't know if you can use CTEs.

select 
from 
(select  from tablea where test is not null or test <>'' or test<>'N/A') a
JOin 
(select  from tableb where test is not null or test <>'' or test<>'N/A')b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest a solution without derived tables. Basically i use a GUI to input my filters and then the tool creates the backend sql. It is tricky to use the gui to create inner queries.

Comment: Then don;t use the gui

Answer (score 0):

Since you want all the rows from A, below query should work:

```
select * from A left outer join B on A.col1 = B.col1 where A.col1 is not null and A.col1<>'N/A' and A.col1<>''
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98501/14

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
select * from A left join B on A.col1 = B.col1
```

NULL will never match anything (when not compared with `IS NULL`and the like), therefore NULL in A won't match anything in B.